# Is there any good tutorials to convert HTML+ CSS to wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, xhtml, wordpress-theming

Is there any good tutorials to convert HTML+ CSS to Wordpress? not PSD 2 HTML? I mean if
HTML CSS is available we just need to convert a XHTML CSS template to installable Wordpress 3.0 Theme? I'm not talking about PSD 2 HTML.

For example this is free CSS template http://www.freecsstemplates.org/preview/regeneracy/ I just want to download it and convert this css template into Wordpress 3.0 installable theme.

My question is just opposite to this question [Convert Wordpress theme to plain XHTML+CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645465/convert-wordpress-theme-to-plain-xhtmlcss)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand how wordpress templating system works. The best way to do this is to go through [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and understand the layout of themes in wordpress.

Even I started converting other CSS templates in to wordpress themes like this. I took out all the basic elements like 'header', 'footer', 'sidebars' and place them in appropriate places in wordpress theme. You can take an existing classic wordpress theme (default) and change it by replacing the elements. Once you start doing this, you will understand how themes work in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an automated tool for that.

[Wordpress themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) are not just Html + Css: you have to call the appropriate Php [Wordpress APIs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) in order to display your posts, categories, comments, etc.

Unfortunately, doing this from scratch is not trivial if you don't have any previous Php or Wordpress experience (it's not impossible either).

A possible alternative is to download an [existing Wordpress theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) and create [a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Frameworks) from it, which basically means you can use it as a template and override some of its settings, for instance the Css file. Unfortunately, it is very unlikely that the Css classes used there would match those of your design, so you would still have to do a lot of tayloring.

Comment: +1 Thanks for reply. I'm not asking for automated way m asking for a tutorial to convert HTML template to Wordpress, manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/). This tutorial is not exactly about converting HTML+CSS to wordpress theme but this gives you a basic idea to create wordpress theme and how it works. After you know how wordpress theme works you can start adding wordpress' template tags and make it compatible with wordpress.